# The react-native cli app turns off as soon as it turns on (Android studio)

Tags: windows, react-native, android-studio, react-native-cli

In the react native cli project, if you enter the yarn android command in the terminal and wait, the android study device starts automatically and turns off again as soon as the application opens. The same happens when you manually press the application. The app won't turn on.

For your information, I use Windows, and this project is a company project, and my predecessor developed it in a Mac environment.

installed : react-native cli, stackflow(webview), Chocolatey, Nodejs, Python, JDK
server : java, springboot, cloudflare
And I've even finished setting environment variables.

For reference, react-native is used for the gps, image, and alert functions.

Since I use webview, I tried to turn on the app with the react project server on, but it didn't work.

`Using react.gradle in your project is deprecated! You should move to "apply plugin: com.facebook.react" react.gradle is going to be removed in a future React Native project and your project will not build anymore. You can use the template as a reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/android/app/build.gradle`

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5rYV.png)